# Selenium Reporting

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, qtp, test-report

During my experience in Quality Assurance, especially automation testing, I have experienced two functional test tools(QTP and Selenium). In fact, I have noticed that Selenium have more strong points than QTP or it's much more dedicated for complicated web application. But still have one weak point  : "Test Reports". For me, I find a big problem in generating reports related to Selenium Test. Otherwise, I find it very easy using QTP.

My question is, What's the best appropriate method used by Selenium Testers to generate tests reports?

Comment: Are looking for TestNG reports or Junit reports?.

Comment: And testers will use the reporting technique based on there need. Not all testers are using same reporting technique's (Available more so).

Answer (score 2):

@Imen: I know below mentioned reporting techniques.

And more important is how you want your reports (Line by line/step by step execution report, class/method level report, etc..?).

*What's the best appropriate method used by Selenium Testers to generate tests reports?*

Selenium will support multiple reports generation techniques. Testers will be using different reporting techniques. The reports generation depend/based on the tester (If no specific requirement is from client/customer end), client requirement/request, etc...

**Ex 1: You can use Log4j**

***Sample code:***

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");

Log.startTestCase("TestCase_001 Started");

driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Log.info("New driver instantiated");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Log.info("Implicit wait applied on the driver for 10 seconds");

driver.get("http://google.com");
```

***For more details refer this link:*** [Link](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-reporting/)

**Ex 2: You can use TestRunner**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

//This result object has many methods and it is very useful

//Type result and press dot, all the methods will display

//This statement is to load all type of results in the result object

Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestRunnerClass.class);

//Here it is getting the run count from the result object

System.out.println("Total number of tests: " + result.getRunCount());
//This is to get the failure count from the result object
System.out.println("Total number of tests failed: " + result.getFailureCount());
//This is to get the time count from the result object
System.out.println("Total time of tests: " + result.getRunTime());

for(Failure failure : result.getFailures())
{    
//This will print message only in case of failure
System.out.println(failure.getMessage());
}
//This will print the overall test result in boolean type
System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
}
```

**Ex 3: Using .xml file**

***Sample Code:***

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

 import org.openqa.selenium.By;

 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

 import org.testng.Assert;

 import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

 public class TestClass1 {

 protected static WebDriver wd;

 protected static String result;

 @BeforeClass

 public static void setup()  {

 wd = new FirefoxDriver();

 wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 }

 @Test

 void Testcase1() {

 wd.get("http://www.floraindia.com");

 wd.findElement(By.id("kwsch")).sendKeys("Red");

 wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@src='images/go.gif']")).click();

 result = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//font[text()='Total Items :']//following::td[1]")).getText();

 Assert.assertEquals(result, "115");

  }

 @Test

 void Testcase2() {

 wd.get("http://www.floraindia.com");

 wd.findElement(By.id("kwsch")).sendKeys("Blue");

 wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@src='images/go.gif']")).click();

 result = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//font[text()='Total Items  :']//following::td[1]")).getText();

  Assert.assertEquals(result, "13");

 }
 @AfterClass

 public static void teardown()  {

 wd.close();

 wd.quit();

 }
```

}

***.XML file sample:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
 <suite name="My sample Suite">
  <test name="Search test">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestClass1" />
    </classes>
  </test>
 </suite>
```

***For more details:*** [Link 2](http://www.faichi.com/blog/automated-selenium-testing-framework-using-testng-webdriver)

Comment: Thanks for your response and the explanations you provide

Answer (score 0):

Talking about JUnit report, both XML and HTML reports can be added by editing Apache Ant build.xml file:

Test running target:

```
 <target name="tests" depends= "compile">
   <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" showoutput="true">
    <classpath refid="junit.classpath"/>
      <formatter type="plain"/>
      <formatter type="xml"/>
  ...
```

Report target:

```
<target name="report">
  <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
      <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
    </fileset>
    <report format="noframes" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
  </junitreport>   
</target>
```